# How can I filter the contents of an accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some difficulties figuring out how to filter through my Accordion Menu. Currently, it is only displaying the name of the Menus, but not it's content. I would like to know if it's possible to search both the name and the content of the Menu, and if it is, how to display it (auto open it).

```js
function sidebarSearch() {

  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, nav, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("sidebarSearch"); // Grab the Search Field
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); // Change typed text to Upper Case (thus eliminating case sensitivity)
  nav = document.getElementById("sidebarNav"); // Grab Link Container
  li = nav.getElementsByTagName("li"); // Grab Link Items

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// Declare variables
var sidebarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarLinks");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < sidebarLinks.length; i++) {

  sidebarLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    // Toggle between hiding and showing the active Menu
    var sidebarMenu = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight) {
      sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight = null;
      sidebarMenu.style.padding = "0px 0px";
    } else {
      sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight = sidebarMenu.scrollHeight + "px";
      sidebarMenu.style.padding = "10px 0px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:active,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
li,
ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  /* padding: 0; */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // Safari/Chrome, other WebKit
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; // Firefox, other Gecko
  box-sizing: border-box; // Opera/IE 8+
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr; */
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #282533 15%, #506367 70%, #58675e 95%)
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 1fr;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebarHeader,
.sidebarContent {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.sidebarContent {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebarSearch {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebarNav {
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebarLinks {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarLinks.active {
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 0px #00a2ff inset;
}

.sidebarLinks:hover {
  /* border-left: 5px solid #00a2ff; */
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 0px #00a2ff inset;
}

.sidebarMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out, padding 0.25s ease-out;
}

.sidebarMenuLinks {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #00a2ff;
  word-break: break-word;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarHeader">
      Sidebar Header
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarContent">
      <input type="text" class="sidebarSearch" id="sidebarSearch" onkeyup="sidebarSearch()" placeholder="Search.." title="Sidebar Topic Search">
      <nav class="sidebarNav" id="sidebarNav">
        <li>
          <a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <nav class="sidebarMenu">
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 1.3</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 1.4</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 1.5</a></li>
          </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <nav class="sidebarMenu">
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 2.3</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 2.4</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 2.5</a></li>
          </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 3</a>
          <nav class="sidebarMenu">
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 3.4</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 4</a>
          <nav class="sidebarMenu">
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 4.1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 4.2</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 4.3</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 4.4</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 4.5</a></li>
          </nav>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 5</a>
          <nav class="sidebarMenu">
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 5.1</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 5.2</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 5.3</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 5.4</a></li>
            <li class="sidebarMenuLinks"><a href="#">Link 5.5</a></li>
          </nav>
        </li>
        <li><a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
        <li><a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        <li><a class="sidebarLinks" href="#">Link 10</a></li>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code so that it searches the content as well as the menus.

The code now shows all content when searching and filters through it so it knows what to show and what to hide. When the search bar is empty, all the content hides and all the menu names show.

### Modified javascript code

```
function sidebarSearch() {

  var nav, li
  nav = document.getElementById("sidebarNav"); // Grab Link Container
  li = nav.getElementsByTagName("li"); // Grab Link Items

  if (document.getElementById("sidebarSearch").value != "") {

    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("sidebarSearch"); // Grab the Search Field
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); // Change typed text to Upper Case (thus eliminating case sensitivity)
    sidebarMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarMenu");

    for (i = 0; i < sidebarMenu.length; i++) {
        sidebarMenu[i].style.maxHeight = sidebarMenu.scrollHeight + "px";
        sidebarMenu[i].style.padding = "10px 0px";
    }

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.display = "";
        } else {
        li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarMenuLinks").length; i++) {
        a = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarMenuLinks")[i];

        console.log(a);
        if (a.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a.style.display = "";
            a.parentElement.style.maxHeight = a.parentElement.scrollHeight + "px";
            a.parentElement.style.padding = "10px 0px";
        } else {
            a.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  } else {
    a = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarMenuLinks");
    sidebarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarLinks");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
        a[i].parentElement.style.maxHeight = null;
        a[i].parentElement.style.padding = "0px 0px";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.display = "";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sidebarLinks.length; i++) {
        if (sidebarLinks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
          var sidebarMenu = sidebarLinks[i].nextElementSibling;

          sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight = sidebarMenu.scrollHeight + "px";
          sidebarMenu.style.padding = "10px 0px";
        }
    }
  }
}

// Declare variables
var sidebarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebarLinks");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < sidebarLinks.length; i++) {

  sidebarLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    // Toggle between hiding and showing the active Menu
    var sidebarMenu = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight) {
      sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight = null;
      sidebarMenu.style.padding = "0px 0px";
    } else {
      sidebarMenu.style.maxHeight = sidebarMenu.scrollHeight + "px";
      sidebarMenu.style.padding = "10px 0px";
    }
  });
}
```